# Qual o problema dessa paginação não responsiva usando boostrap 4 no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, layout-responsivo, paginação

Estou utilizando Laravel para fazer um sistema, junto com o *framework* *Bootstrap*. E estou utilizando o recurso de paginação. Porém estou com problemas para deixar responsivo os numeros da paginação. Ambos estão desconfigurados referente a tabela, e estão ultrapassando os cantos. Abaixo está o exemplo.

[image: paginaçãoDesconfigurada]

Estou tentando centralizar ou deixar alguns números de paginação justapostos. Porém toda a vez que redimensiono para o modo Celular (*mobile*), ocorre a sua desconfiguração. Abaixo está o codigo do que estou utilizando no Laravel.

```
            <nav class="nav d-flex justify-content-center">
                <ul class="pagination p-4 pagination-sm flex-wrap">
                    {{ $prospect->appends($data)->links() }}
                </ul>                    
            </nav>
```

Também adicionei o código [aqui](https://www.bootply.com/Ne9SYj0yN7), junto a tabela que estou utilizando. Logo olhando o meu código do *bootply*, percebe-se que não há problema nenhum, mas utilizando a paginação do Laravel, acontece diferente no *front-end*.

Estou com dúvidas se a paginação do Laravel pode mesmo interferir no *front-end* ou é apenas um erro básico de mal uso do *boostrap* 4.

Como posso estar consertando esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc colocou as classes de `flex` no lugar errado! Elas tem que estar na `ul` e não na `div`

```
        <nav class="nav ">
            <ul class="pagination p-4 pagination-sm d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
                {{ $prospect->appends($data)->links() }}
            </ul>                    
        </nav>
```

Segue um exemplo, repare que as classes de `flex` estão na `ul`, não na `div`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<nav class="nav w-50" >
    <ul class="pagination p-4 pagination-sm d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary m-1">1</li>
    </ul>                    
</nav>
```

Comment: Não sei o que pode diferenciar, mas seria preciso postar o resto do código com a tabela junto? Aqui comigo não funcionou dessa maneira. Tipo, ele não fica justo ao centro, somente se colocar o justify-content-center no nav. E ainda passa do tamanho da tabela.

Comment: @ArthurAbitante como o código que vc postou na pergunta o máximo que da para te ajudar é isso... Se vc puder atualizar a pergunta e colocar a tabela como ela é renderizada no browser, tipo abre no navegador, da um Ctrl+U e pega a tabela já renderiza. Ai testa para ver como ela fica de forma insolada em uma página em branco. Isso vai te ajudar a ver se o erro é nela ou se é outra coisa que está na pagina que está atrapalhando. Mas só com o seu código da pergunta não da para ajudar mais que isso :/

Comment: Acabei de editar a questao, o código se encontra aqui, https://www.bootply.com/Ne9SYj0yN7. parece que terei que extender a pergunta para o Laravel. Pois alguma coisa na paginação do Laravel está interferindo também.

Comment: @ArthurAbitante então deve ser isso pq mesmo na ambiente que vc montou funciona certinho http://prntscr.com/peigfv Confere se o Laravel está colocando estilos inline na sua tag HTML, da uma inspecionada nos elemento depois de renderizado para ver se identifica algo